# eclipse error when trying to build gradle project - sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed

Tags: eclipse, gradle, jar

Apart from adding certificates into the JRE security folder using "keytool -keystore cacerts -importcert -alias <> -file ". Should something similar be done from eclipse too. I had to add this certificate to download jars from a particular repo. After adding this certificate i was able to build and download jars through cmd but not through eclipse. Getting this error - sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException

Comment: Did you do a manual refresh? It depends on how you are integrating with Gradle. e.g.: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-i-get-gradle-to-include-jars-in-my-eclipse-referenced-libraries/3295

Comment: I did a manual refresh and found that the error is due to missing certificate. But i did install this certificate and able to download jars when i try build with command prompt. For some reason this error occurs only with eclipse.

Comment: apart from adding the certificate into the JRE security folder using "keytool -keystore cacerts -importcert -alias <> -file <PATH>". Should something similar be done from eclipse too. I had to add this certificate to download jars from a particular repo. After adding this certificate i was able to build and download jars through cmd but not through eclipse. Getting this error - sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException

Comment: A lot of theses details should be in the body of the question, as it clarifies the problem being asked about and changes the nature of any questions. Perhaps reword things so you are asking about these certs.

Comment: Have you solved this?